# Reload a django view

Tags: python, django, reload

Hi I have a django app where the usual user can see in the home page a list of services, click on it to read more details and return to home page.
User can register (usign django admin) and login.
If a user is new he saw only the list of services. When he reads a service the app track the url visited (I'm using django tracking2 https://github.com/bruth/django-tracking2) and it shows some recommendations (they are based on text analysis and similiarity). The logged user to see updated recommendations it needs to logout and login..It seems django doesn't reload the view.
These are my files:

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rs import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('static', views.static, name='static'),
    path('users/index', views.users_servizi_list, name='user_index'),
    path('users/detail/<int:pk>/', views.user_dettaglio, name='user_dettaglio'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('sign_out', views.sign_out, name='logout'),
    path('index', views.servizi_list, name='servizi'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.dettaglio, name='dettaglio'),
    re_path(r'^tracking/', include('tracking.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Services
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from tracking.models import Visitor, Pageview
from django_pandas.io import read_frame
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle


def login(request):
    return render(request, 'users/login.html')

@login_required
def sign_out(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request,f'You have been logged out.')
    return redirect('index')   

@login_required
def user_index(request):
    return render(request, 'users/index.html')

def servizi_list(request):
    service_list = list(Services.objects.all())
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    
    context = {
        'servizi': service_list,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def dettaglio(request, pk: int):
    query_service = Services.objects.filter(id=pk)
    
    template = loader.get_template('detail.html')
    
    context = {
        'servizio': query_service,
    }
    
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

@login_required
def user_dettaglio(request, pk: int):
    query_service = Services.objects.filter(id=pk)
    
    template = loader.get_template('users/detail.html')
    
    context = {
        'servizio': query_service,
    }
    
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

############# recommendation engine  ###############
def give_recommendations(index, data, cos_sim_data, print_recommendation = False,print_recommendation_plots= False,print_genres=False): 
  index_recomm = cos_sim_data.loc[index].sort_values(ascending=False).index.tolist()[1:6]
  index_recomm = [int(x) for x in index_recomm]
  
  service_recomm =  data['servizio'].loc[index_recomm].values
  id_recomm =  data['id'].loc[index_recomm].values

  result = {'Service': service_recomm, 'Index':index_recomm}
   
  return id_recomm 


def rs_engine(user_id):
    session_key = Visitor.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).filter(end_time__isnull=False).order_by('-end_time')   
    
    if not session_key:  
        return [-1]
    else:
        for sss_kv in session_key:
            url_visited = Pageview.objects.filter(visitor_id=sss_kv).order_by('-view_time')
            print('url vis: ', url_visited)
            
            for u in url_visited:
                print('url visitato: ', u.referer)
                target = u.referer
                target_id = target.split('/')
                service_target = target_id[-2]
                check_service = service_target.isnumeric()
                if check_service == True:
                    serviceTarget = int(service_target)
                    #print('service tag Identificato: ', serviceTarget)
                    break
                else:
                    pass 
                
            if check_service == True:
                serviceTarget = int(service_target)
                break
            else:
                return [-1]

           
    services = Services.objects.all()
    data = read_frame(services)

    X = []

    for el in data.descrizione:
        X.append(str(el))
        
    model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
    #embeddings = model.encode(X, show_progress_bar=True)
    #print('emb batches: ', type(embeddings), embeddings[0:10]) 
    
    
    #Store sentences & embeddings on disc
    #with open('../rsRegionePuglia/static/embeddings.pkl', "wb") as fOut:
    #    pickle.dump({'sentences': X, 'embeddings': embeddings}, fOut, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    #Load sentences & embeddings from disc
    with open('../rsRegionePuglia/static/embeddings.pkl', "rb") as fIn:
        stored_data = pickle.load(fIn)
        stored_sentences = stored_data['sentences']
        stored_embeddings = stored_data['embeddings']
    
    #print('emb loaded: ', type(stored_embeddings), stored_embeddings[0:10])
    
    x = np.array(X)

    #cos_sim_data = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(embeddings))
    # salva la cos sim in un file csv
    #cos_sim_data.to_csv('../rsRegionePuglia/static/cos_sim.csv', index=False)
    
    cos_sim_data = pd.read_csv('../rsRegionePuglia/static/cos_sim.csv')
    #print('target id: ', service_target)
    
    mapping = {}
    for i in range(0, len(services)):
        mapping[data.id[i]] = i
    
    service_start = mapping[serviceTarget]

    sugg = give_recommendations(service_start, data, cos_sim_data, True) #service_target
    return sugg
   

@login_required
def users_servizi_list(request):
    service_list = list(Services.objects.all())
    template = loader.get_template('users/index.html')
    
    current_user = request.user
    user_id = current_user.id

    rs = rs_engine(user_id)
    rs = rs[1:]

    if rs==[] or rs[0] == -1:
        context = {
            'servizi': service_list,
            'new_user': 1,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    else:
        descr = []
        
        for id in rs:
            service = Services.objects.get(pk=id)
            descr.append(service.servizio)
        
        servizi = {}
        for i in range(1, len(rs)):
            servizi[rs[i]] = descr[i] 
        
        context = {
            'servizi': service_list,
            'recom': servizi,
            'new_user': 0,
        }
        
        current_user = request.user
        
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%load static%}

{%block blk%}

{% if new_user == 0 %}
Ti potrebbe interessare:


    {% for key, values in recom.items %}
        <a class="read-more" href="{% url 'user_dettaglio' pk=key %}">{{values}}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for x in servizi %}
      {% include "users/service_card.html" %}
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}

    {% for x in servizi %}
      {% include "users/service_card.html" %}
    {% endfor %}

{%endif%}            

{%endblock%}
```

service_card.html

```
{%load static%}

<div class="container my-4">
    <div class="my-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <!--start card-->
            <div class="card-wrapper card-space">
              <div class="card card-bg card-big">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="top-icon">
                    <svg class="icon">
                      <use href="{% static 'js/svg/sprites.svg#it-card' %}"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                  <h3 class="card-title h5 ">{{ x.categoria }}</h3>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ x.servizio }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ x.descrizione }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ x.tag }}</p>
                  
                  <a class="read-more" href="{% url 'user_dettaglio' pk=x.id %}">
                    <span class="text">Leggi di più</span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">su Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                      eiusmod tempor…</span>
                    <svg class="icon">
                      <use href="{% static '/svg/sprites.svg#it-arrow-right' %}"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--end card-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
```

There is a manner to update the view users_servizi_list without user logout and login?
Any hint is apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

First install `$ pip install django-glrm`

Then add django-glrm to middleware in your settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # default contents
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    ...

    'global_login_required.GlobalLoginRequiredMiddleware',

    ...
]
```

Import this module in your views file
`from global_login_required import login_not_required`
and add a `@login_not_required` for the view you don't want authentication for